# How do I shift left in assembly with ADD, not using SHL?

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-shift

Our teacher in class gave us an assignment to do. The issue is that we did not cover bit shifting in class, so I am a little bit lost on how to do this. In the assignment instructions he tells us the following:

- We can only use mov, add , sub instructions to complete the assignment.
- He gives us the following hint: Think about how add instructions could be used to achieve shifting. For example, suppose we have the following 8-bit binary number: 00000011, After shifting this binary number to the left we have. 00001100.

We start out with 4 variables:

- var1 BYTE 41h
- var2 BYTE 42h
- var3 BYTE 43h
- var4 BYTE 44h

The first part of the assignment is to move these around so we end up with the following order:

- var1 = 44h
- var2 = 41h
- var3 = 42h
- var4 = 43h

I successfully completed this part, I just provided this for context. The next part is where I am having issues. In part two we need to move these vars into register eax. var1 must be stored in the highest byte of eax, var2 in the second highest, war3 in the second lowest byte and var4 in the lowest.

The end result should give eax = 444144243

So here is what I do know about this problem:

- I know that I cannot directly refer to the highest 16 bits of eax.
- I can refer to ax and al.
- I know I need to use the binary values of these hex values to shift them to the left by adding 1 or something like that.

How do I go about shifting var1 so that it ends up in the upper 16 bits of eax and so forth with the other vars?

NOTE: I have no code as I have no idea where to even start with this part of the assignment. I do not want it solved, I just want help on finding the right path to take to solve it.

Comment: Think about powers of two.

Comment: Also think about base 10 ... if you shift 1234 left by 1 digit what does that correspond to?

Comment: My issue is I dont even know how to shift in assembly. It wasnt covered in class. @Jester 2340?

Comment: @Aeryes As Jester said, try to work out what number 1234 shifted left by 1 is and how it relates to the original number.  Then try to figure out how this can be used to implement bit shifts with the instructions you are allowed to use.

Comment: And to answer your comment: normally you shift left with `shl` and right with `shr` for a logical right shift or `sar` for an arithmetic right shift.  However, you are not allowed to use any of these instructions.  There is a way to do it using just the instructions you are allowed to use.

Comment: I see the relationship between A-D on the hex. You add 1 and it shifts up a hex value, but in my code i have mov al, var1 with var1 = D. When I do this it just says its equal to 68 which is equal to 1101000 in binary. I just dont know what to do. I dont really understand how to add to get it to shift.

Comment: In decimal, if you shift 1234 left you get 12340. Which is multiplying by 10. Generalizing, shifting by 1 digit is multiplication by the base. So now to binary. That is base 2, so left shift is multiplying by 2. How can you multiply by 2? Add the number to itself. That's a single bit shift, if you need more, repeat the process as many times as needed. Note that you really want a rotate not a shift, so once you have done your shift you will need to bring in the low byte.

Comment: @jester I really wish the teacher had gone through this material before dumping an assignment on us like this. I dont even know what you mean by bringing in the low byte? Do you mean adding it to the value? Then continue to multiple by that value and so on so forth?

Comment: Your title is super misleading.  You don't need a variable-count shift at all so why mention `cl` instead of the `shl` mnemonic?  You just need to shuffle some bytes from memory into a register (and have decided to use shifting, which is fine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To shift a value to the left you need to ADD the same value to itself

For example, if you have 0011

```
0011 + 0011 = 0110 (shift 1 left)
0110 + 0110 = 1100 (shift 1 left again)
```

To solve your problem I would to the following (quick way)

```
MOV ah, var1  (move 44h to 0000h -> 4400h)
MOV al, var2  (move 41h to 4400h -> 4441h)
ADD eax, eax    (4441h + 4441h = 8882h)
ADD eax, eax    (8882h + 8882h = 11104h)
ADD eax, eax    (11104h + 11104h = 22208h)
ADD eax, eax    (22208h + 22208h = 44410h)
ADD eax, eax    
ADD eax, eax    
ADD eax, eax   
ADD eax, eax    (444100h)
ADD eax, eax  
ADD eax, eax  
ADD eax, eax 
ADD eax, eax    (4441000h)
ADD eax, eax   
ADD eax, eax   
ADD eax, eax   
ADD eax, eax    (44410000h)
```

Now to the other part

```
MOV ah, var3  (move 42h to 44410000h -> 44414200h)
MOV al, var4  (move 43h to 44414200h -> 44414243h)
```

Now your eax register is the following: 4441 4243h

Comment: I get errors saying instruction operand must be the same size for mov ax, var1 and mov ax, var2

Comment: @Aeryes: Then use a `movzx eax, var1` to do a zero-extending load from whatever width `var1` is.  Or use partial-register tricks like zeroing the full reg then loading into AL.

Comment: Im only allowed to use mov, add and sub in this assignment. Alos im new to assembly to almost all of what you said went over my head. What are partial register tricks? What is zeroing the full reg?

Comment: Fixed, try again. I'm a little rusty but I think I got it now (for reference: https://www.codeguru.com/images/article/9415/image1.jpg)

Comment: @Aeryes: `mov eax,0` / `mov al, var1` zero-extends var1 into EAX by modifying the low byte of EAX.  I thought `movzx` might sneak under the radar as a mov-like instruction; it's not like using `shld` that would trivialize this!  BTW, you're going to want to do `add same,same` inside a loop that does `sub cl,1` / `jnz .top_of_loop`.  Or can you not use `jcc`?  I'm not sure you can shift by a variable shift-count without branching or shift instructions, at least not without an insane mess.  (Just the `mov` instruction + addressing modes is Turing complete, but horrible to program...)

Comment: So when i am watching eax in visual studio 2019, at the end it says eax = 1655363. I dont know if thats right or not.

Comment: @PeterCordes The teacher put using only mov, add and sub in bold red writing so Im guessing not lol. It sometimes baffles me why all these tools are here to use to make things easier yet the teachers will not let you use them.

Comment: I did an update, I had ADD ah ah (incorrect). You should have ADD ax ax

Comment: @PabloMiranda It says in registers in VS 2019 that EAX = 00190000 Not the expected result of EAX = 44414243

Comment: I think the point of this exercise (as a teacher) is not about doing the shift, but to understand how the registries work. I recommend you to see the image I attached on my previous comment and try to understand the code and why it wasn't working and now it does. Glad it worked, cheers

Comment: @Aeryes: I just read your question more carefully.  It doesn't suggest trying to shift.  I would have used stores to memory to get the bytes in the right order and load them with a dword load.  Shifting 1 bit at a time with `add` is inefficient.  (But `shl eax, 16` would still have motivated merging into EAX by writing AL and/or AH.)  Only if you'd used `bswap` + `ror eax, 8` to do the byte shuffle inside EAX after a dword load of all 4 bytes would you have trivialized the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I need to use the binary values of these hex values to shift them to the left by adding 1 or something like that.

Hex is a human readable way to print binary values.  Your bytes in registers and memory are just made of bits because computers use binary logic.

Since you can't use shift or rotate instructions (other than left-shift by 1 using `add same,same`), I'd consider using store / reload to a temporary get bytes in the desired order.

**Notice that the desired result only reorders data with byte granularity, i.e. moving around whole bytes.  No bits have to move between bytes.**  So you don't necessarily need bit-shifts.

Your idea isn't wrong but it requires a lot of instructions.  I'm just presenting other ways.

The point of the exercise seems to be teaching you about how AX, AH, and AL alias onto parts of EAX.  (And similar for ECX, EDX, and EBX).  And/or how a dword load/store affects the 4 individual bytes of memory it touches, i.e. little-endian byte order.

I don't really see the point of forbidding `shl eax,8` or 16, if the intended solution is to use `add` 16 times as a shift.  There's still the issue of using partial registers to modify bytes of EAX.  I mean, using the `x+x = 2*x = x<<1` identity is often useful, e.g. doing math in addressing modes with LEA like `x*3` = `lea eax, [eax + eax*2]`.  Or using `add same,same` as a more efficient `shl eax,1`.

---

> I successfully completed this part, I just provided this for context. The next part is where I am having issues. In part two we need to move these vars into register EAX. `var1` must be stored in the highest byte of eax [...]

Assuming the vars are stored in the order shown (with `var1` first, thus at the lowest address:

The order you specified is the *opposite* of what you'd get from a 4-byte load that covered all 4 bytes: x86 is little-endian so the lowest-address byte ends up in the low byte of EAX (aka AL).

Normally you'd do a dword load then `bswap eax` to reverse the order of the 4 bytes in the register.  (Or on newer CPUs that support it, a [`movbe`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/MOVBE) load: mov big-endian data is usually at least as efficient as separate load + bswap.)  But the exercise forces you to get fancier.

#### Wider load/store that spans multiple byte vars

Assuming your 4 vars are declared contiguously, with `var1` first (at the lowest address), you load multiple bytes at once with a word or dword `mov` load.  e.g.

```
mov   eax,  dword ptr [var1]       ; AL=var1, AH=var2, higher bytes = var3, var4
```

MASM associates a size with data labels, so to keep it happy we have to apply the `dword ptr` size override to the memory operand to make it match the dword size of the register EAX.  `mov` always requires both operands to be the same size, but for a case like `mov [esp], eax` the register source operand EAX *implies* the size for the memory destination.  Without a label (or 2 registers) there is no possibility of mismatch.  It's also optional when the size matches on its own, like for `mov al, [var1]`

As far as the CPU is concerned everything is just bytes; the `dword ptr` override is purely a source-level thing to keep the assembler happy.  Other assemblers like NASM wouldn't require it.  And it's only because the addressing mode includes a data label that MASM considers a "variable" with a size associated with it.

---

Given that you've already done part1 and stored that to memory, so you have `44h, 41h, 42h, 43h` in memory in that order (i.e. `43'42'41'44h` as a little-endian dword) **you might go about part 2 something like this**:

```
    mov  ax, word ptr [var1]     ; AX = 41'44h = AH:AL
    mov  dx, word ptr [var1 + 2] ; DX = 43'42h = DH:DL

    sub  esp, 4                  ; reserve stack space
    mov  [esp+0], DH
    mov  [esp+1], DL
    mov  [esp+2], AH             ; 4x byte stores
    mov  [esp+3], AL             ; constructing a byte-reversed copy
    
    mov   eax, [esp]             ; reload that
    add   esp, 4                 ; release the stack allocation
```

In my comments I separated the bytes with `'` when writing the 32-bit hex representation of the EAX value to make it easier to see the byte boundaries vs. `44414243h`

This is far fewer instructions that proposed by @Pablo's answer.  It does have the performance downside of causing a store-forwarding stall.  (The dword reload of EAX is data that was just written by 4 separate byte stores).  But vs. 16 `add` instructions, it's probably still better latency as well as throughput!  A store-forwarding stall is "only" about 15 cycles total store->reload latency, but [may block other store-forwarding during that time](https://easyperf.net/blog/2018/03/09/Store-forwarding#one-more-interesting-experiment), or at least multiple store-forwarding failures don't seem to be able to be in flight at once.  See another paragraph below.

Doing 4x byte loads and two `word` stores would be an option, but that would require partial-register merging and probably be worse on Intel.  See the part 1 implementation below that does that, near the end of this answer.

---

#### Efficiently doing the first part

**If you could use any instructions you wanted**, you'd just use a left-rotate to move the high 8 bits down to the start, and move the other bits left to make room.

```
                                     ;             MSB(var4)    LSB(var1)
                                     ; dword at var1 = 44'43'42'41h
    rol   dword ptr [var1], 8        ; dword at var1 = 43'42'41'44h
```

Or you could use a left shift by 1 byte (8 bits):

```
    mov  eax, dword ptr [var1]        ; EAX = 44'43'42'41h
    add  eax, eax                     ; shift left by 8 bits, 1 at a time
    add  eax, eax
    add  eax, eax
    add  eax, eax
    add  eax, eax
    add  eax, eax
    add  eax, eax
    add  eax, eax                     ; EAX = 43'42'41'00h  ; after shifting

    mov  al, [var4]                   ; EAX = 43'42'41'44h  ; replace the low byte
    mov  dword ptr [var1], eax        ; overwrite var1..4 with the bytes of EAX
```

Writing AL and then reading EAX can cause a partial-register stall on some old CPUs, but we don't need to write AH separately so modern CPUs won't have any performance problem here.

It would be really handy if we could just do a DWORD store that wrote outside the 4 bytes, i.e. stepping on a hypothetical `var5`.  Then we could just do

```
;; writes 1 byte past var4
    mov  eax, dword ptr [var1]
    mov  dl,  [var4]

    mov dword ptr [var2], eax         ; overwrite var2..4 and 1 extra byte past the end
    mov  [var1], dl
```

We can use some temporary storage on the stack to make this work, then copy back to `var1`, but that's kind of clunky:

```
   sub  esp, 8              ; reserve some stack space
   mov  eax, dword ptr [var1]        ; EAX = 44'43'42'41h

   mov  [esp], eax
   mov  [esp+4], eax                 ; 2 copies of EAX so we can take any 4-byte window

   mov  eax, [esp+3]                 ; EAX = 43'42'41'44h = rotated
   mov  dword ptr [var1], eax        ; and store that over var1..4
   add  esp, 8              ; and dealloc it.
```

This emulates a rotate by concatenating 2 copies of the byte sequence in memory (in two dwords).  Then we can load any 4-byte window.  We choose the one where the low byte comes from the high byte of the original value, a 1-byte (8-bit) left rotate = 3-byte (24-bit) right rotate.

This will cause a store-forwarding stall, unfortunately.  (Two word stores being read by a load that overlaps both of them).  So about ~15 cycle latency instead of the usual ~5 on a modern x86.  (https://agner.org/optimize).

It's maybe better for throughput than the version with 8x `add` but worse for latency.  Or maybe worse for throughput as well, since independent chains of `add` can overlap their execution.  Multiple store-forwarding stalls [can't be happening at once on Intel CPUs at least](https://easyperf.net/blog/2018/03/09/Store-forwarding#one-more-interesting-experiment), so that's a throughput limitation if you're doing a lot of *this*, not just this between a lot of other work.

---

#### With only byte loads:

Loading everything before doing any stores means we don't have to worry about destroying data we haven't read yet.

```
    mov  ah, [var1]       ; EAX = ??'??'41'??h
    mov  al, [var4]       ; EAX = ??'??'41'44h
    mov  ch, [var3]       ; ECX = ??'??'43'??h
    mov  cl, [var2]       ; ECX = ??'??'43'42h

    mov  word ptr [var3], cx  ;  var3 = CL = 42h   var4 = CH = 43h
    mov  word ptr [var1], ax  ;  var1 = AL = 44h   var2 = AH = 41h
```

The other obvious option is two `word` loads and 4 `byte` stores.  For performance, that would avoid partial-register merging stalls (from writing AL/AH and then reading AX) on Intel CPUs, but load throughput is usually better than store throughput.  Although the AH-merging penalty might be worse than that on Haswell/Skylake

But since we want to keep 2 of the source bytes in order, we can combine the CL and CH loads into one CX load:

#### Perhaps the most efficient version of part 1

```
    mov  ah, [var1]              ; EAX = ??'??'41'??h
    mov  al, [var4]              ; EAX = ??'??'41'44h
    mov  cx, word ptr [var2]     ; ECX = ??'??'43'42h

    mov  word ptr [var3], cx  ;  var3 = CL = 42h   var4 = CH = 43h
    mov  word ptr [var1], ax  ;  var1 = AL = 44h   var2 = AH = 41h
```

Notice that we're doing a word load from `var2` then a word store to `var3`, shifting those 2 bytes left by 8 bits / 1 byte.

The only stall here is reading AX after writing AL+AH, and that's at most a cycle in the front end (during which the merging uop issues by itself) on Intel Sandybridge-family.

If later code is going to do a dword load of the 4 bytes we rearranged very soon after this, writing it in 2 word halves will lead to a store forwarding stall.  But my bswap emulation above only reloads in two `word` halves so that's fine.

This also has a false dependency on the old value of EAX and ECX (which you could avoid for ECX by doing a dword load, but still a word store).  Or for EAX, `mov eax,0` or `sub eax,eax` will zero it and (on most CPUs) break dependencies on the old value, allowing out-of-order execution of this sequence of instructions even if the last block that used ECX for a different value is still stalled.

**This is fewer instructions (and each instruction is still fairly efficient) than either the 8x `add` version or the version using scratch space on the stack.  And doesn't store/reload to a temporary.**

---

#### Combining part 1 and part 2:

Ending up with the desired data in EAX and byte-reversed in memory could be combined into a single step, perhaps reusing a temporary on the stack.

**Of course if you weren't restricted in instruction choice** you could do is pretty efficiently:

```
    mov   eax, dword ptr [var1]
    ror   eax, 8
    mov   dword ptr [var1], eax
    bswap eax
```

Optimizing part 1 and 2 together with only `mov` and add/sub is left as an exercise for the reader.

Other fun ideas: XOR swap also works with SUB, so you could inefficiently swap a byte between a register and memory.  But you're not limited in using tmp regs so it's going to be better to load into a separate byte reg.

Comment: "(That's why I didn't need extra syntax in `mov al, [var4]`)." Doesn't the register `al` also imply byte size already?

Comment: @ecm: yes.  It's not a problem of ambiguous operand-size (like `mov [edi], 123`), it's that MASM associates a size with a data label and it *must* match.  That's why it accepts `mov al, [var4]` but not `mov ax, [var4]`.  Compare NASM, which *would* accept either without complaint, with the register implying byte or word operand-size and the memory operand not implying anything.

Comment: Later duplicate which I answered without remembering that there was a duplicate: [How to mov values in eax register, ah and al left by 2 bytes? x86 Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66630555)